# Instant search depending on a UITextView content

Tags: iphone

I want to display results instantly while user enters some information (like google search). For now, I am doing this using a button. Is there a way to do it instantly? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its not a joke.. try to accept your previous answers.. and "I am doing this using a button" I cant able to understand this.. can you explain it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the search field is a UISearchBar in its delegate you can implement:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)srcBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundAutocomplete:)
                           withObject:searchText];
}
```

and do something useful in the "backgroundAutocomplete" method, like populating a UITableView with suggestions.
The method will be called every time a user types a character...